# Build in Visual Studio Team Services (was Visual Studio Online) - Azure Web App Deployment succeeds but web app not updated

Tags: continuous-integration, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service, azure-pipelines

I am trying to configure some Continuous Integration to automatically deploy my MVC application to my an Azure hosted test web site, driven from a VSTS build definition (as opposed to Azure Integrate with source control).

All seems to work with the build and the deployment step "succeeds", but the actual **web site is not updated**. I have tried a google search, but have not found anything providing an explanation to my problem. Publishing from Visual Studio 2015 (i.e. desktop development environment) to the Azure web app works as expected.

Is there an issue with my build definitions (described below)? Could deploying from desktop prior to setting up the Team Services build definition impact the build? Could it be a (mis)configuration issue on the Azure web app? Should I have my build definition just do the build and a separate "Release" definition do the publishing?

Setup:

Team Services to host the GIT repository and the build definition.

Azure Web App, "Shared" tier, all default configuration except for some connection string definitions.

My Team Services's team's "Admin" section has a Service set up for my Azure portal, using certificate based authentication
Git repository has a "Development" branch

Build is set up as follows (almost entirely default, apart from setting `clean` on build, and choosing my Azure subscription/website. Set up to build on checkin to Development branch, all other tabs left as default). All steps are Enabled:

- NuGet Restore (working)
- Build Solution: Args: `/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:PackageLocation="$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\\"`, platform: `$(BuildPlatform)`, Configuration: `$(BuildConfiguration)`, Clean: `checked`
- Test Assemblies (working)
- Azure Deployment (Subscription: `my azure service`, Web app location/name: `as per hosted website on Azure (picked from the dropdowns)`, Slot: `[not defined, I am on a "shared hosting" web site`, Web Deploy package: `$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\**\*.zip`
- Publish symbols path [no really sure if this is relevant to my issue]... Search Path: `**\bin\**\*.pdb`
- Publish Artifact: drop [not relevant to problem]: Path to publish: `$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)`

All steps of the build "pass" (i.e. get a green tick). I can download the package that was built, and can see that the datestamp on DLLs match the time that I triggered the build, so I am confident it is building correctly.

The Azure Deployment steps *appear* to indicate success. I have pasted the last few lines, but have changed any credentials for privacy:

```
2016-07-12T23:00:14.9575943Z Get-AzureWebSite -Name mysitename -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -ErrorVariable azureWebSiteError -Slot Production
2016-07-12T23:00:26.9251171Z WebSite 'mysitename' found.
2016-07-12T23:00:26.9261179Z Publish-AzureWebsiteProject -Name "mysitename" -Package "C:\a\1\a\MyApp.zip" -Slot "Production"  -ErrorVariable publishAzureWebsiteError
2016-07-12T23:00:47.8533773Z Updating deployment status
```

There is no error, but on the same note, there is no "successfully completed" action. The `SilentlyContinue` parameter in the `Get-AzureWebSite` concerns me, but I do not know how to change it.

Thanks!

Comment: I didn't see any issue with configurations in your build definition and no "successfully completed" action for Azure Deployment steps is also expected behavior. To narrow down the issue, can you download the published build artifact and check if the change is indeed included in the package? Check date-stamp is not enough.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Turns out the date stamp was not being updated, but the build was going through successfully. I have learned my lesson about making a proper change to see if a deployment is successful :) In fact, I added a powershell step to increment the assembly version number, and displayed that, so I can always see something changing.